# How To Redirect The Page After Successfull Form Submission PHP Header is not working

Tags: php, forms

Here is my code to register a user.when i click on signup the url in header function is not generated with passing variable success.it just shows The upper section of form header

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['success']) && empty($_GET['success'])){

        $msg= "You Have Been Registered!";
        echo $msg;
        }
    else{
        if(empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true){
        $register_data = array(
            'user_name' => $_POST['username'],
            'password' => $_POST['pass'],
            'email' => $_POST['email'],
            'mobileno' => $_POST['cell'],
            'gen' => $_POST['gen'],
            'first_name' => $_POST['firstname'],
            'last_name' => $_POST['lastname']
        );
        register_user($register_data);
        echo "redirecting to";
        header("location:../../core/Admin/registrationform.php?success");
            exit();
        }else if(empty($errors) === false ){
            echo output_errors($errors);
        }

    }
        ?>


    </div>
  <form  method="post" action="">

            <label>First Name*</label> <input type="text" name="firstname"/> 
            <label>Last Name</label> <input type="text" name="lastname"/>  
            <label>Gender*</label> <input type="text" name="gen"/>  
            <label>User Name*</label> <input type="text" name="username"/> 
            <label>Email*</label> <input type="text" name="email"/>
            <label>Mobile No* (Must Be Given)</label> <input type="text" name="cell"/>  
            <label>Password*</label> <input type="text" name="pass"/>  
            <label>Confirm Password*</label> <input type="text" name="confirmpass"/>
             <label>Write The Answer Of* :</label> <input type="text" name="ans"/> 
            <input id="resetbutton" type="reset" value="Reset Fields"/>
            <input id="submitbutton" type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up"/>  
        </form>
```

Comment: If below answer works for you please considering to give accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
header('Location: url..?success=1');
```

Call full url in header function

or

Use jQuery function to redirect to a page

```
window.location
```

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp

refer this link

Comment: Deeban Babu i have used this but i want to redirect to the same page with a message u have been registered

Comment: pass parameter with url  like url..?success=1 and check that page receives succes parameter

Comment: Did you try like this header("location:registrationform.php?success");

Comment: i have tried all the possible methods....if i remove exit() after header("location:registrationform.php?success");....then it goes to the same page but with no message displayed....

Comment: no it is not receiving success parameter.....the main problem is that the header is not working it does not change the url after submission of form....

Comment: In your code $_GET['success'] is empty.
Try this header("location:registrationform.php?success=success");

Answer (score 0):

There is trick , use ob_start() in first line after `<?php`

Comment: Its impossible , it ll redirect to URL which you added in header("location:XXXXX?success")

Comment: the main problem is that it is not redirecting...when i submit the form the data is inserted in the database but the in address bar the header address is not generated....

Answer (score 0):

Always remember if you are going to redirect to any page then you should not print anything before that otherwise you will get error something like header already sent....just remove

```
 echo "redirecting to";
```

before **header** function

check this code

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['success']) && empty($_GET['success'])){

        $msg= "You Have Been Registered!";
        echo $msg;
        }
    else{
        if(empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true){
        $register_data = array(
            'user_name' => $_POST['username'],
            'password' => $_POST['pass'],
            'email' => $_POST['email'],
            'mobileno' => $_POST['cell'],
            'gen' => $_POST['gen'],
            'first_name' => $_POST['firstname'],
            'last_name' => $_POST['lastname']
        );
        register_user($register_data);

        header("location:../../core/Admin/registrationform.php?success");
            exit();
        }else if(empty($errors) === false ){
            echo output_errors($errors);
        }

    }
        ?>


    </div>
  <form  method="post" action="">

            <label>First Name*</label> <input type="text" name="firstname"/> 
            <label>Last Name</label> <input type="text" name="lastname"/>  
            <label>Gender*</label> <input type="text" name="gen"/>  
            <label>User Name*</label> <input type="text" name="username"/> 
            <label>Email*</label> <input type="text" name="email"/>
            <label>Mobile No* (Must Be Given)</label> <input type="text" name="cell"/>  
            <label>Password*</label> <input type="text" name="pass"/>  
            <label>Confirm Password*</label> <input type="text" name="confirmpass"/>
             <label>Write The Answer Of* :</label> <input type="text" name="ans"/> 
            <input id="resetbutton" type="reset" value="Reset Fields"/>
            <input id="submitbutton" type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up"/>  
        </form>
```